# Specify column added order in a WPF Grid in code behind?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Adding a column to a grid in code behind is easy:

```
col10 = new ColumnDefinition();
col10.SharedSizeGroup = "column1";
```

When you add the column it adds to the end of the grid for example you have a grid with columns A and B, you use the code above and a new column (C) and it is added as A B C.

Is it possible to set it up like this?

C A B

Instead on adding to the end its added to the front?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ColumnDefinitions` are like any other Collection and support the IList<> interface.
So just use an insert method to control added order.

```
ColumnDefinition myColumn = new ColumnDefintion();
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(0, myColumn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridAddColumn.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Name="cbWhere" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBoxItem>Front</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>End</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>

            <TextBlock Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            <TextBox Name="tbName" MinWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            <Button Content="Create" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click" />

        </StackPanel>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="grid" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DataGridAddColumn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddColumn(DataGrid grid, string name, int where)
        {
            if (where == 0)
            {
                grid.Columns.Insert(0, new DataGridTextColumn{Header = name});
            }
            else
            {
                grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = name });
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddColumn(grid, tbName.Text, cbWhere.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```